# Position of mat-select-panel opened by the mat-paginator pagination dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material

Steps to reproduce:

- Click the paginator dropdown, select 20
- Click the paginator dropdown again

Expected Behavior
The options should be close to the select input

Actual Behavior
The options position is wrong

[image]

Comment: Please create a stackblitz sample

Comment: Ok i will share